# flask project compile in cython then deploy or run

Tags: python, python-3.x, flask, cython

I have a Python flask app and I need to compile with cython and then deploy or run it. Following [this guide](https://medium.com/@xpl/protecting-python-sources-using-cython-dcd940bb188e), I can compile simple python application. I need to do the same thing to a simple flask app and then run it. my Flask==1.0.2

flaskPractise.py:

```
#!flask/bin/python3

from flask import Flask, url_for
app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def api_root():
    return 'Welcome'

@app.route('/articles/<articleid>')
def api_article(articleid):
    return 'You are reading ' + articleid

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=8000)
```

compile.py :

```
from distutils.core import setup
from distutils.extension import Extension
from Cython.Distutils import build_ext

ext_modules = [
    Extension("flaskPractise", ["flaskPractise.py"])
]
setup(
    name = 'My Program Name',
    cmdclass = {'build_ext': build_ext},
    ext_modules = ext_modules
)
```

main.py:

```
from logic import main
main()
```

after running `python3 compile.py build_ext --inplace` command flaskPractise.c file and flaskPractise.cpython-37m-x86_64-linux-gnu.so is created.now how do i run this?

Comment: [Accordingly to docs](https://cython.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/tutorial/cython_tutorial.html), just `import flaskPractise` and `flaskPractise.app.run()`

Comment: Did u ever get this to work? I tried to reproduce this & followed @Fian but I can't import flaskPractise, I keep getting **import: not authorized `flaskPractise' @ error/constitute.c/WriteImage/1028** error in the terminal. I'm using this in a conda env